# How to select files that have no extension using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a drive with lots of directories and files, some of which are broken and have no file extension.  I would like to delete all of the files that do NOT have an extension.  I have tried `gci | where {$_.extension -eq ""}` and `gci | where {$_.extension -eq "."}` and variations of those, but end up getting nothing or everything on the drive.

If I look at the results of `gci | select Extension` the files show nothing for the extension, just like a directory, not sure where to go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
gci -File -Recurse | ?{!($_.Extension)}
```

Comment: Additionally, if you wanna assign some extension commonly to all those extension-less files then just run this: `gci -File -Recurse | ?{!($_.Extension)} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + '.<ext>'}`, easy peasy!.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest and fastest solution (**PSv3+**) is to use the **`-Filter` parameter**:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51718337/45375).

As for a **pipeline-based solution**:

**PowerShell *Core*** now offers the `-Not` switch with the simplified comparison statement syntax that itself was introduced to `Where-Object` (whose built-in alias is `?`) in Windows PowerShell v3, which enables the following, more concise variant of [TheMadTechnician's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21739887/45375):

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object -Not Extension
```

As in TheMadTechnician's answer, this uses *implicit Boolean logic*: any *nonempty  string* evaluates to `$True` in a Boolean context, so applying `-Not` means that `$True` is only returned if the string *is* empty, i.e., if the file has no extension.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`gci | where {$_.extension -eq ""}` works in principle, except that it also includes *directories*.

In PSv3+ you can use the `-File` switch to limit the results to *files*, as above.

In **PSv2** you must add a condition to the script block, based on the `.PSISContainer` property only returning `$True` for *directories*:

```
gci | where { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.extension -eq "" }
```

Comment: What a spectacular explanation! Thank you for expanding on my extremely rudimentary answer. I really need to go back and flesh out my earlier answers like the one above (or perhaps below depending on future votes) to improve quality. Though in my defense I had only joined SO 2 weeks before writing that.

Comment: I appreciate the nice feedback, @TheMadTechnician. Yes, the teaching-a-person-to-fish angle is important, in the simplest case with just a link to the docs. Still, a working answer even without explanation is better than none, and I get how it can get tiresome to explain certain things over and over.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | where {!$_.PsIsContainer -and ![io.path]::hasextension($_.name) }
```