# How do I use Get-ChildItem to return files that don't have an extension?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I want to get a list of files that don't have a filename extension. Consider the content of my directory to be:

```
folder
file1
file2.mp4
```

My goal would be to get `file1` only.

Running `Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.* -File` returned nothing.

Running `Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.*` returned `folder` and `file1`.

Running `Get-ChildItem -File` returned `file1` and `file2.mp4`.

Any idea if there is any way of using Get-ChildItem to only return `file1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **PSv3+**, but **doesn't work in PowerShell *Core* v6.x, fixed in v7** (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9330)):

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.
```

- `-File` limits output to just files (as opposed to directories).
- `-Filter *.` selects only those files that have no extension.

`-Filter` is generally preferable to `-Include` / `-Exclude` for performance reasons, because it filters *at the source*, rather than returning all objects and letting *PowerShell* do the filtering.

In **PSv2**, where the `-File` switch isn't available, you need an additional `Where-Object` call to limit the results to *files*, as [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) points out:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *. | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Slower **PowerShell *Core*** solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object -Not Extension
```

---

**Optional background information**:

That **a `-Filter` argument is processed by the underlying provider, not by PowerShell**, means that its behavior may differ from PowerShell's, which is indeed the case here: the FileSystem provider uses the **Windows API's wildcard-expression matching, which has fewer features than PowerShell's as well as some historical quirks**; also, it is limited to a *single* wildcard expression, whereas `-Include` / `-Exclude` support multiple ones (separated with `,`).

Here, however, `-Filter` offers something that PowerShell's wildcard matching doesn't: using `*.` to match files / directories without extension.

**`-Include` / `-Exclude` generally offer functional advantages at the expense of performance, but they have their own limitations and quirks**:

- `*.` isn't supported to match items without extension in [*PowerShell*'s wildcard language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards), and there is no wildcard-based way to achieve this that I know of.
- `-Include` / `-Exclude` operate on the *last component* of the *specified or implied* path, so if you're implicitly targeting the current directory, they apply to that *directory path*, not to the individual files inside.

  - Specifying `-Recurse` changes that, but that searches the entire directory *subtree*.
  - While you *should* be able to add `-Depth 0` to limit matches to the immediate child items while still being able to apply `-Include` / `-Exclude`, this is *broken* as of Windows PowerShell v5.1: The `-Depth` argument is *ignored* in this case.
    This problem has been fixed in PowerShell *Core*, however.

In short: `-Include` / `-Exclude` offer no solution here.